# nginx proxy based on location

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I would like to setup an nginx proxy that is based on a location instead of the listening port or server_name.

```
upstream cluster
{
    server cluster1:8080;
    server cluster2:8080;
}
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location /hbase
    {
        proxy_pass http://cluster;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;
    }
}
```

I know this is probably something really simple that I am missing.  Basically the routing seems to work, but it actually ends up calling "http://cluster1:8080/hbase"  when it should just route the traffic to the server without the hbase portion.

A rewrite rule would work, but I can't seem to find a way to rewrite in nginx; I can get it to redirect, but I want the actual port to be invisible to the outside world.

This works perfectly, but I only want to allow traffic on port 80.

```
upstream cluster
{
    server cluster1:8080;
    server cluster2:8080;
}
server
{
    listen 555;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://cluster;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;
    }
}
```

Is there possibly a way to use regex to remove hbase from the forwarded request?

**ANSWER:**

```
location /hbase
{
    rewrite  ^/hbase$|^/hbase/$|^/hbase/(.*)$ /$1  break;
    proxy_pass http://cluster;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an efficient [rewrite](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) in *nginx*. The following should work (didn't try)

```
  location /hbase
  {
     rewrite  ^.*$  /  break;
     proxy_pass http://cluster;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried that, but wasn't thinking to add all three cases into the regex.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know there was something after `/hbase/`. Glad it works!